# Django MVT design: Should I have all the code in models or views?

Tags: python, django

I'm pretty novice so I'll try to explain in a way that you can understand what I mean.

I'm coding a simple application in Django to track cash operations, track amounts, etc.

So I have an Account Model (with an amount field to track how many money is inside) and an Operation Model(with an amount field as well).

I've created a model helper called Account.add_operation(amount). Here is my question:

Should I include inside the code to create the new Operation inside Account.add_operation(amount) or should I do it in the Views?

And, should I call the save() method in the models (for example at the end of Account.add_operation() or must it be called in the views?)

What's the best approach, to have code inside the models or inside the views?

Thanks for your attention and your patience.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you could use the rule **"skinny controllers, fat models"** to decide. Well in django it would be "skinny views".

To save related objects, in your case `Operation` I'd do it in the `save()` method or use the [pre_save](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/signals/#connecting-to-signals-sent-by-specific-senders) signal

Hope this helps

Comment: Do you mean overriding the default save() method of the Account model? (sorry if I misunderstood :) )

And thanks for your help!

Comment: yeap, u can override the `save()` method to create an organization and then call the parent method... maybe it's better to make a signal

Answer (score 0):

Experienced Django users seem to always err on the side of putting code in models. In part, that's because it's a lot easier to unit test models - they're usually pretty self-contained, whereas views touch both models and templates.

Beyond that, I would just ask yourself if the code pertains to the model itself or whether it's specific to the way it's being accessed and presented in a given view. I don't entirely understand your example (I think you're going to have to post some code if you want more specific help), but everything you mention sounds to me like it belongs in the model. That is, creating a new `Operation` sounds like it's an inherent part of what it means to do something called `add_operation()`!